# How to change Woocommerce price?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The prices of products on my site are collected through a robot.
All prices are in Turkish lira.
I want the price of all products to be converted into dollars.
I used this code snippet.

```html
function regular_price_func( $price, $product )
{
    //your logic for calculating the new price here
     $price = $product->get_regular_price()*1.3;

    //Return the new price (this is the price that will be used everywhere in the store)
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'regular_price_func', 99, 2);
```

But when the special selling price is active for the product, the prices are wrong.

New codes:

```js
// Change/Update Regular price 
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'regular_price_func', 10, 2 );
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'regular_price_func', 10, 2 );
 function regular_price_func( $regular_price, $product ) {
      $rate = 1.3;
      if( empty($regular_price) || $regular_price == 0 ){
        return $product->get_price() * $rate;  
      } else{
        return $regular_price;  
      }
      
 }

 // You can also Change/Update Sale price 
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'woo_sale_price_price_func', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'woo_sale_price_price_func', 10, 2 );
 function woo_sale_price_price_func( $sale_price, $product ) {
     $rate = 1.3;
     if( empty($sale_price) || $sale_price == 0 )
      return $product->get_regular_price() * $rate;
      else
     return $sale_price * $rate;
 };
```

Comment: Do you mean - When the product is on sale?

Comment: @Howard E If the price was on sale, change both the regular price and the sale price. and  If the price is not on sale, just change the regular price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You can change the sale price and regular price and update the condition accordingly.

```
//Change/Update Regular price 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'regular_price_func', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'regular_price_func', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'regular_price_func', 10, 2 );
function regular_price_func( $regular_price, $product ) {
    $rate = 1.3;
    if( empty($regular_price) || $regular_price == 0 ){
    return $product->get_price() * $rate;  
    } else{
    return $regular_price * $rate;  
    }
    
}

// You can also Change/Update Sale price 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'woo_sale_price_price_func', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'woo_sale_price_price_func', 10, 2 );
function woo_sale_price_price_func( $sale_price, $product ) {
    $rate = 1.3;
    if( empty($sale_price) || $sale_price == 0 )
    return $product->get_regular_price() * $rate;
    else
    return $sale_price * $rate;
};
```

Comment: Did you test this code? It does not work.

Comment: If the price was on sale, change both the regular price and the sale price. and  If the price is not on sale, just change the regular price.

Comment: Yes i have tested and its working perfectly for me

Comment: You can change/update on regular_price_func accordingly for sale price/ regular price. If you want to change both prices, please uncomment woo_sale_price_price_func function alse and you can modify accordingly

Comment: @ Rajeev Singh I used your code. But there is no change in prices. I put the code I used in the question section.(The question section has been updated)

Comment: @yasintaqizade, Now I have also updated my answer, please try this, it's also working from the end and I have also tested. you can check also https://www.loom.com/share/16286687299f42089368ac548f01bf51

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to alter either the regular price OR the sale price.  You have to specify which ones you want to use.

Also, the hook `woocommerce_product_get_price` is deprecated as of 3.0, the replacement for this is `woocommerce_get_price` - and finally, this filter returns price as a string, so to multiply a value, you need the `floatval` of that string.

```
function regular_price_func($price, $product) {
    if ($product->is_on_sale()){
        $price = floatval($product->get_sale_price()) * 1.3;
    } else {
        $price = floatval( $product->get_regular_price() ) * 1.3;
    }
    //Return the new price (this is the price that will be used everywhere in the store)
    return $price;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'regular_price_func', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: I want to change both prices.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'your_foo', 10, 2 );

function your_foo( $price, $product1 ) {
//  global $product;
//  $product_price = $price;
//  if ( isset( $product ) ) {
//      $product_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_price', true );
//  }
    $price = $product_price - 23;

    return $price;
}
```